# How do I sanitize these params for a user-supplied query?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am seeing some Airbrake errors that tell me my users are having issues searching for things that PSQL thinks are REGEX when in fact it should treat it as a pure string.

The error is:

```
Parameters: {"terms"=>"P[", "id"=>"29"}
  Inventory Load (0.5ms)  SELECT name, number, id FROM "inventories" WHERE (name ~* 'P[' OR number ~* 'P[')
PG::InvalidRegularExpression: ERROR:  invalid regular expression: brackets [] not balanced
: SELECT name, number, id FROM "inventories"  WHERE (name ~* 'P[' OR number ~* 'P[')
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 117.8ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidRegularExpression: ERROR:  invalid regular expression: brackets [] not balanced
: SELECT name, number, id FROM "inventories"  WHERE (name ~* 'P[' OR number ~* 'P[')):
```

My code uses a the fuzzy search of PSQL to search the entire cell for a match anywhere in the string:

```
@inventory =
      Inventory.select("name, number, id")
        .where("name ~* :key OR number ~* :key", :key => key)
```

key is just passed into this method by the user from a search field in the UI.  Someone tried to store an Inventory item as something like 'P[akjhdfkgjhdg]' and now they want to search for it.  They should be able to.

Why does PSQL interpret it as REGEX?

EDIT:

The answer submitted to 'marked as duplicate' is not what I'm asking.  I am not asking how to escape brackets.  I am asking how to SANITIZE A STRING (where I do not know what characters might existing in the string) such that when ActiveRecord creates the sql to the DB, *any* characters which might confuse Postgres into thinking that I'm passing a REGEX are sanitized so that they will be treated as a common string.

I cannot possibly imagine every single symbol customer might enter in the search field, so I cannot come up with some crazy matcher to check for things.  I want something like 'sanitize_array' or 'sanitize' in Ruby / Rails, and I have tried such methods documented on API Dock, but none of them work.

Comment: You have to scape the special chars.

Comment: Bracket characters have special meaning in a LIKE clause and need to be escaped. See the duplicate reference above.